# How to change the alignment on the listview header

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I'm working on a Modern, C#/XAML Win8 app. I have a page that is essentially a big listview, with a header that is an image. This works out quite nicely and gives the desired user experience I was looking for.

One problem, I want to center the image and the rest of the listview into the center of the page.

I managed to center the listview items this way:

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

I have not been able to figure out how to style the header. Here is the code to display the header:

```
<!-- The header of the listview is the image -->
<ListView.HeaderTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Viewbox MaxHeight="480" Width="660">
            <Image 
                x:Name="image"
                Source="{Binding ImageBig}"/>
        </Viewbox>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.HeaderTemplate>
```

Does anyone know how I could accomplish this?

Thank you very much for any help!

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong you can set the listview HorizontalAlignment and VerticalAlignment to Center and for your image you can try setting the HorizontalContentAlignment and VerticalContentAlignment of the viewbox to Center hence if it doesn't work try using a grid instead. You should be able to find it in the properties tab else you can also code it at the code behind or on the xaml itself.